# Replace with regular expression a string with a list of strings in python

Tags: python, list, python-re

I want to replace part of a string with a list of strings

Eg. with an input string of `'{"abc": "##value##", "Xyz": 2}'`,
I want to replace `"##value##"` with some list like `["v1", "v2"]`

So, the output would look like `'{"abc": ["v1", "v2"], "Xyz": 2}'`

If the replacement were not a list I would have just used

`re.sub('##value##', replacement_value, input_data)`, however doing so gives an error of
`unhashable type: 'list'`

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change

```
re.sub('##value##', replacement_value, input_data)
```

to

```
re.sub("'##value##'", str(replacement_value), input_data)
```

---

`re.sub()` only takes in strings as the substitutes, so it's the equivalent of

```
import re
s = '{"abc": "##value##", "Xyz": 2}'
print(re.sub('"##value##"',  '["v1", "v2"]', s))
```

Output:

```
{"abc": ["v1", "v2"], "Xyz": 2}
```